# Is the only difference between Inductive and CoInductive the well-formedness checks on their uses (in Coq)?

Tags: coq, coinduction, corecursion, codata

To phrase the question differently: if we were to remove termination-checking and the guardedness condition on uses of inductive and coinductive data types, respectively, would there cease to be a fundamental difference between inductive/coinductive and fix/cofix?

By "fundamental difference" I mean a difference in the core calculus of Coq–not differences in things like syntax and proof search.

This seems to ultimately boil down to a question about the Calculus of Constructions.

Note: I know a theorem prover that skipped termination-checking/guardedness of recursion/corecursion could prove `False`–so, if it helps, please take this as a question about non-total programming rather than proving.

Answer (score 5):

The termination check for fix and cofix is part of their well-formedness rules. If we ignore that, the other important distinguishing feature of those constructs is in the computation rules.

- `fix` only reduces if its decreasing argument is a constructor
- `cofix` only reduces when under a destructor (`match` or a primitive projection)

```
(* stuck *)
(fix f x {struct x} := body f x)

(* not stuck *)
(fix f x {struct x} := body f x) (S y)
=
body (fix f x := body f x) (S y)


(* stuck *)
(cofix g x := body g x)

(* not stuck *)
match (cofix g x := body g x) with _ => _ end
= match body (cofix g x := body g x) x with _ => _ end
```

Those peculiar rules are that way in order to ensure termination. If you do not care about that, and allow `fix` and `cofix` to unfold in any context, then they behave identically as a fixpoint combinator:

```
(fix f x := body f x)
=
(fun x => body (fix f x := body f x) x)

(cofix g x := body g x)
=
(fun x => body (cofix g x := body g x) x)
```